# Как использовать несколько data-price атрибутов для вывода в jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Прошу помочь с одним затруднением. Есть два переменных с несколькими элементами, у каждого из них есть атрибут data-price. Функционал должен работать как калькулятор. Нужно чтобы данные каждой переменной прибавлялись и выводились в нужном месте. Функционал работает но к сожалению прибавляется и выводятся данные только одной переменной в двух местах одновременно. Как нужно использовать разные data-price чтобы получить разные результаты? P.S. Ниже приведен код. Там где "руб" не видит data-price своего элемента, а там где "руб/месяц" все работает правильно. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

```js
$('.left_tab .onoffswitch-checkbox').on('click',function(){
                checked = $(this).prop('checked');
                allPrice     = $('.js-subscription-price-summ').text();
                allPrice2     = $('.js-connection-price-summ').text();
                allPrice     = parseInt(allPrice.replace(/\s/g, ''));
                allPrice2     = parseInt(allPrice2.replace(/\s/g, ''));

                modifyPrice = parseInt($(this).attr('data-price').replace(/\s/g, ''));
                modifyPrice2 = parseInt($(this).attr('data-price').replace(/\s/g, ''));

                if (checked) {
                    sum = allPrice+modifyPrice;
                    sum2 = allPrice2+modifyPrice2;
                } else {
                    sum = allPrice-modifyPrice;
                    sum2 = allPrice2-modifyPrice2;
                }

                $('.js-subscription-price-summ').text(sum);
                $('.js-connection-price-summ').text(sum2);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <section class="ру-16 table_block">
            <div class="container mx-auto tabb">
<div class="left_tab">
<div class="product-option js-product-option">
<div class="col-name">
    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png"
title=""></div>
</div>
<div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="500">500&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб</span></div>
<div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">590&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб/месяц</span>
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input class="onoffswitch-checkbox" data-price="590" id="wired_option_6907" name="wired_option_6907" type="checkbox">
        <label class="onoffswitch-label"for="wired_option_6907"></label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="product-option js-product-option">
<div class="col-name">
    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png"
title=""></div>
</div>
<div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="300">300&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб</span></div>
<div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost"
    >590&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб/месяц</span>
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input data-price="590" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="wired_option_6908" name="wired_option_6908" type="checkbox">
        <label class="onoffswitch-label"for="wired_option_6908"></label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="product-option js-product-option">
<div class="col-name">
    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png"
title=""></div>
</div>
<div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="100">100&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб</span></div>
<div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost"
    >590&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб/месяц</span>
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input data-price="590" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="wired_option_6909" name="wired_option_6909" type="checkbox">
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6909"></label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="product-option js-product-option">
<div class="col-name">
    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png"
title=""></div>
</div>
<div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="400">400&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб</span></div>
<div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost"
    >590&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб/месяц</span>
    <div class="onoffswitch"><input data-price="590" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="wired_option_6910"
            name="wired_option_6910" type="checkbox"><label class="onoffswitch-label"
            for="wired_option_6910"></label></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="product-option js-product-option">
<div class="col-name">
    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png"
title=""></div>
</div>
<div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="0">Бесплатно</div>
<div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost"
    >590&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб/месяц</span>
    <div class="onoffswitch"><input data-price="590" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="wired_option_6911"
            name="wired_option_6911" type="checkbox"><label class="onoffswitch-label"
            for="wired_option_6911"></label></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="product-option js-product-option">
<div class="col-name">
    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png"
title=""></div>
</div>
<div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="0">Бесплатно</div>
<div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost"
    >590&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб/месяц</span>
    <div class="onoffswitch"><input data-price="590" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="wired_option_6912"
            name="wired_option_6912" type="checkbox"><label class="onoffswitch-label"
            for="wired_option_6912"></label></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="product-option js-product-option">
<div class="col-name">
    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png"
title=""></div>
</div>
<div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="0">Бесплатно</div>
<div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost"
    >590&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб/месяц</span>
    <div class="onoffswitch"><input data-price="590" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="wired_option_6913"
            name="wired_option_6913" type="checkbox"><label class="onoffswitch-label"
            for="wired_option_6913"></label></div>
</div>
</div>
            </div>
            <div class="right_tab">
                <div class="right_tab_info">
                <div class="title">Общая стоимость</div>
                    <div class="price"><div class="price-title">Подключение</div>
                    <div class="price-value"><strong class="connection-price-summ js-connection-price-summ">20 500</strong> <span class="rub">руб</span></div></div>
                    <div class="price">
                        <div class="price-title">Абон. плата</div>
                        <div class="price-value">
                            <strong class="js-subscription-price-summ">10 350</strong>
                        <span class="rub">руб</span>
                            /месяц
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
            </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому, что вы используете для переменно `modifyPrice` и `modifyPrice2` одно 'значение'
Можно попробовать для переменно `modifyPrice2` сделать так -

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.col-connection-cost').attr('data-price') -
```

Мы достаем пра прародителя и в нем ищем класс `col-connection-cost` из которого достаем второе значение

Может не лучшее решение, но работает

```js
$('.onoffswitch-checkbox').on('click', function() {
  checked = $(this).prop('checked');
  allPrice = $('.js-subscription-price-summ').text();
  allPrice2 = $('.js-connection-price-summ').text();
  allPrice = parseInt(allPrice.replace(/\s/g, ''));
  allPrice2 = parseInt(allPrice2.replace(/\s/g, ''));

  modifyPrice = parseInt($(this).attr('data-price').replace(/\s/g, ''));
  modifyPrice2 = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.col-connection-cost').attr('data-price').replace(/\s/g, ''));

  if (checked) {
    sum = allPrice + modifyPrice;
    sum2 = allPrice2 + modifyPrice2;
  } else {
    sum = allPrice - modifyPrice;
    sum2 = allPrice2 - modifyPrice2;
  }

  $('.js-subscription-price-summ').text(sum);
  $('.js-connection-price-summ').text(sum2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="ру-16 table_block">
  <div class="container mx-auto tabb">
    <div class="left_tab">
      <div class="product-option js-product-option">
        <div class="col-name">
          <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png" title=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="100">100&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб</span></div>
        <div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">200&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб/месяц</span>
          <div class="onoffswitch">
            <input class="onoffswitch-checkbox" data-price="200" id="wired_option_6907" name="wired_option_6907" type="checkbox">
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6907"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-option js-product-option">
        <div class="col-name">
          <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png" title=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="200">200&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб</span></div>
        <div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">300&nbsp;<span class="rub">руб/месяц</span>
          <div class="onoffswitch">
            <input data-price="300" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="wired_option_6908" name="wired_option_6908" type="checkbox">
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6908"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_tab">
      <div class="right_tab_info">
        <div class="title">Общая стоимость</div>
        <div class="price">
          <div class="price-title">Подключение</div>
          <div class="price-value"><strong class="connection-price-summ js-connection-price-summ">100</strong> <span class="rub">руб</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
          <div class="price-title">Абон. плата</div>
          <div class="price-value">
            <strong class="js-subscription-price-summ">200</strong>
            <span class="rub">руб</span> /месяц
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```